# How to get transaction details from filter in web3.py

Tags: web3.py

I am developing a software that listens for pending transactions.

```
...
web3 = Web3(HTTPProvider(cfg.eth_node_url))
web3_pending_filter = web3.eth.filter('pending')
transaction_list = web3.eth.getFilterChanges(web3_filter.filter_id)
...
```

In documentation of web3.py [here](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.html#filters) is written that filter's getFilterChanges method should return transaction objects (list of dictionaries), but I am receiving list of hashes only. How can I get list of 'full' transactions from filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs you linked to are showing examples from filtering for events. Since you are filtering for pending transactions, it will be a bit different.

When listing pending transactions, you only get the transaction hashes, as specified in the [json-rpc spec](https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#eth_getfilterchanges):

> For filters created with `eth_newPendingTransactionFilter` the return are transaction hashes (DATA, 32 Bytes), e.g. `["0x6345343454645..."]`.

So you would get the list of transaction details using something like:

```
transaction_hashes = web3.eth.getFilterChanges(web3_filter.filter_id)
transactions = [web3.eth.getTransaction(h) for h in transaction_hashes]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get transaction details via

```
web3.eth.getTransaction(txnHash)
```

If no transaction for the given hash can be found, then this function will instead return None.
https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#looking-up-transactions

In the following paragraph in the above documentation, you can check if the transaction has been mined(included into the blockchain) or not:

```
web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(txnHash)
```

If the transaction has not yet been mined then this method will return None.